# How to use original navigation menu HTML of which structure is different from that of “<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>”?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, flexbox

I'm new to wordpress.

Is it possible to use original HTML for navigation menu and edit its titles and URLs in wordpress admin?

My navigation HTML looks like this.

```
<nav>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a>Menu1</a>
      <div class="slideToggleThis">
        <ul>
          <li><a>Menu1-1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Menu1-1-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Menu1-1-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Menu1-1-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a>Menu1-2</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Menu1-2-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Menu1-2-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Menu1-2-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="hamburger">
    <li><a id="hamburgerFont"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>MenuS</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">MenuA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MenuB</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MenuC</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

As you can see from this, my nav has div between ul and li. The div is necessary because the nav is arranged with Flexbox, thus slideToggle from JQuery doesn't work properly without it (slideToggle changes affected elements' display to block which is not good for display: flex;).

As long as I know, HTML code created by "?php wp_nav_menu(); ?" is simple combination of ul and li which is different from mine.

Are there any solution for me to edit my original HTML navigation menu in wordpress admin? or should I manually change the php files every time I change the contents in the menu?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of changing the structure of the WordPress menu. I'm not that good in explaining the exact code but this url may help you:

https://github.com/roikles/Wordpress-Bem-Menu

He creates a new navigation setup, based on BEM method, to create a new structure.

By calling `bem_menu(` you can add the navigation (read docs for more info). Here you can adjust your settings.